# Is there a way to fill a div visually with elements in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So suppose I have a div which is horizontal with many children, I am appending elements to it with JS  When there's enough children to fit right by eachother horizontally then do it that way. When there is no ability to fit a new one, make a new row to fill with elements and shrink them. At some point, the elements become too small so keep making new rows without shrinking.
Is this an included feature of CSS I do not know about or I would have to do all of this manually through JS?

Comment: Have you made any attempt at this? Or is it just an idea?

Comment: You can try this using CSS flex with the flex-wrap property.
Here you can see an example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap

Comment: @SurajSanwal Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for! I can decrease the size of the elements manually with JS. Please turn this comment into an answer so I could mark it as correct

Comment: Glad to see it helps. Sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this using CSS `flex` with the `flex-wrap` property.

Here you can see an example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap